# Connecting an oracle database to TOAD for Oracle using a Cloud Wallet

Tags: oracle, toad, oracle19c

I have recently downloaded toad for oracle and i want to connect it to my databases but all I have is a cloud wallet for the database.

I have tried to unzip the cloud wallet and point the toad to that location so it can read the tnsnames.ora file but it did not work. I tried editing the current TOAD tns file and adding the host, port, service name and the credentials but it still did not connect. I kept getting a lot of different errors for example connection failed. file could not open

I do not know how to configure TOAD for it to connect.
Can anyone guide me in the process, I researched it a lot but nobody seem to do it often.

Comment: Did you install instant client or you have any database installed on your PC?

Comment: @Sam yes the oracle client is installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is entirely an Oracle Client configuration issue; there is nothing to do in TOAD itself. You need to either unzip the cloud wallet into your ORACLE_HOME/network/admin directory, or unzip it to a custom directory and set the TNS_ADMIN environment variable to point that directory. Note that TNS_ADMIN must be set *before* you start TOAD.

Here's one reference I found:

- https://forums.toadworld.com/t/toad-connection-to-oracle-cloud-autonomous-database-using-wallet/48202